# rails - comparing DateTime to DateTime.now

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, time, datetime-format

I have a rake task that is supposed to go through my Task model, and if the time_frame attribute is in the past (DateTime.now > task.time_frame), should put some information.  Here is the code:

```
task :change_it => :environment do
  @tasks = Task.already_expired
  @tasks.each do |task|
      puts "Kalabar" + task.inspect + "now time is:" + DateTime.now.to_s
  end
end
```

Task.already_expired is defined in the Task model like this:

```
def self.already_expired
    where("time_frame < ?", DateTime.now)
end
```

The problem is, it is printing all tasks, not just past tasks.  Here is the output of running 'rake change_it':

```
Task Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE (time_frame < '2013-12-04 17:25:37')
    Kalabar#<Task id: 3, title: "task 1 - past", content: "Should show this one", 
        created_at: "2013-12-04 17:05:53", updated_at: "2013-12-04 17:05:53", 
        schedule_id: 2, amount: nil, time_frame: "2013-12-02 08:15:00">
        now time is:2013-12-04T12:25:37-05:00
    Kalabar#<Task id: 5, title: "another task - past", 
        content: "should show this one", created_at: "2013-12-04 17:11:23", 
        updated_at: "2013-12-04 17:11:23", schedule_id: 3, amount: nil, 
        time_frame: "2013-12-03 02:07:00">now time is:2013-12-04T12:25:37-05:00
    Kalabar#<Task id: 6, title: "another task - future", 
        content: "should not show at first", created_at: "2013-12-04 17:11:23",
        updated_at: "2013-12-04 17:25:09", schedule_id: 3, amount: nil, 
        time_frame: "2013-12-04 12:27:00">now time is:2013-12-04T12:25:37-05:00
```

As you can see on the first line in the code snippet above, it is looking for

```
time_frame < '2013-12-04 17:25:37'.
```

I have no idea where it is getting 17:25:37 from.  How do I fix this?  Thanks.

UPDATE:

I didn't realize that 17:25:37 was the current time in UTC.  The problem is i need to convert the datetime that the user inputs into UTC before putting it into the database.  Does anyone know how to do this?

UPDATE:

My question has changed since i posted this question.  Here is the new question:  [rails - convert DateTime to UTC before saving to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20384404/rails-convert-datetime-to-utc-before-saving-to-server)

Comment: Use (Date)Time.current instead of DateTime.now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting `17:25:37` because [`DateTime.now`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#now-method) returns a date-time object denoting the present time.

You could either use `DateTime.now.to_date` or `DateTime.now.midnight` if you want tasks with `time_frame` less than or equal to "Yesterday".

**Update:** 
To set `time_frame` to UTC, add the following model to your `Task` class.  Please update the format in `strptime` appropriately, according to your need:

```
# app/models/task.rb

def time_frame=(value)
  write_attribute :time_frame, Date.strptime(value, "%m/%d/%Y").to_datetime.utc if value.present?
end
```

Comment: I do want it to denote the present time.  I didn't realize that 17:25:37 was the current time in UTC.  The problem is i need to convert the date time that the user inputs into UTC.  Do you know how to do this?

Comment: @Philip7899, `DateTime.now.utc` should give you the date in `UTC`.

Comment: Datetime.now is already in UTC.  I need to convert Task.time_frame to UTC before it saves to the database.

Comment: @Philip7899, `UTC` should be default unless you've modified in `application.rb`.  Anyway, to set `Task.time_frame` please see update above.

Comment: Thanks, my question has changed slightly since I've posted it.  Here is the new question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20384404/rails-convert-datetime-to-utc-before-saving-to-server